# How can I profile setTimeout functions existance in JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events, profiling

I am having a problem understanding which function runs (probably in infinite loop) in my JS code.

Is there a plug\way to see the list of the `setTimeout` functions that are running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is hook into your `setTimeout` function and log stuff:

```
var _temp = setTimeout;
setTimeout = function() {
      _temp.apply(this, arguments);
      alert(arguments[0]);
};
```

Put that snippet at the top of your code. Every time anything invokes `setTimeout`, you'll see exactly who's doing it.

Also, instead of `alert`, use `console.log` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the Firebug Firefox extension to put a breakpoint in. http://getfirebug.com/